# Access a Relationship field inside a Playa field

Tags: playa, stash, relationships

I have a Playa field that contains related People to display on a page. In each Person entry there is a standard EE Relationship field (pre EE2.6) to assign the Office Location.

What I need to do is show the telephone number from the Office Location, but can't figure out the best way to do it.

Here is my code;

```
{exp:playa:children field="page_people"}
    {exp:stash:append_list name="page_people" parse_tags="yes"}
        {stash:person_title}{title}{/stash:person_title}
        {!--This is the relationship field for Telephone--}
        {stash:person_telephone}{related_entries id='person_office'}{location_telephone}{/related_entries}{/stash:person_telephone}
    {/exp:stash:append_list}
{/exp:playa:children}
```

When the page renders, it just displays as {REL[person_office]6g2JK3WuREL}.

If anyone can offer a suggestion, I would be grateful.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The `{related_entries}` tag was used in EE1, but is no longer used in EE2.

Instead, to call in data from a native EE2 relationship field, you need to use a looping tag pair. For example:

```
{your_relationship_field}
    {your_relationship_field:title}
    {your_relationship_field:a_custom_field}
{/your_relationship_field}
```

If your relationship field only accepts one single entry, you can also just use a single tag without the loop, like so:

```
{your_relationship_field:a_custom_field}
```

You can find more detailed examples in the [EE documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/relationships.html) documentation.

So, your code `{related_entries id='person_office'}{location_telephone}{/related_entries}` should be:

```
{person_office:location_telephone}
```

Comment: Thanks Katrin. Unfortunately that syntax is for EE version 2.6+. I'm only on EE 2.5.4.

Comment: My mistake, sorry. Should have read your questions properly.

Have you tried adding 
`{exp:playa:children field="page_people"}
{related_entries id='person_office'}{location_telephone}
{/related_entries}
{/exp:playa:children}`
within a channel loop to your output/view template directly? Does it return the correct value then?

Comment: Hi Katrin, no it just returns the {REL[person_office]6g2JK3WuREL} code.

Comment: Does template debugging shed any light?